# Is it bad naming convention to have a model named "model"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, naming, convention

Specifically in Ruby on Rails. I have a model and controller dedicated to 3D models and unfortunately "model" was the best name I could come up with.

I'm not sure if this is a subjective question so forgive me if it is.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it... but it could lead to some misunderstanding if you would be working with more people on this project in the future... therefore you could consider adding some prefix to it: ScaleModel, table: scale_models or something.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any problem with this.

Check out this app which provides an easy search against any reserved words in Rails. http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/